# Flash should open window in new tab, but instead it opens a new pop up on Mac

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, macos, firefox, cross-platform

using `target="_blank"` in the `navigateToUrl`

with Firefox on Windows it opens in new tab, with Firefox on Mac it opens a 'popup',

How to make the window popup in a new tab on Firefox on Mac as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Firefox preferences >> Tabs >> New windows should be opened in (a new window | a new tab). Do you have different settings for your Firefox on your Windows and on your Mac?

Answer (score 2):

That is a browser preference, not an actionscript property.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug in the browser and/or plug-in. My suggestion would be to try telling JavaScript to open the window, using ExternalInterface. This may be more likely to trigger a pop-up blocker though.